# Linq grouping question

Tags: linq

I have the following objects in a collection:

**Transaction:**
Type = "Widget"
Date = "3/1/2011"
Name = "Foo"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Widget"
Date = "3/4/2011"
Name = "Bar"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gadget"
Date = "3/2/2011"
Name = "Baz"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gizmo"
Date = "3/1/2011"
Name = "Who"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gizmo"
Date = "3/2/2011"
Name = "What"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gizmo"
Date = "3/6/2011"
Name = "When"

I want to end up with the following, grouped by Type.  If there are multiple, return only the first one chronologically by date.

**Transaction:**
Type = "Widget"
Date = "3/1/2011"
Name = "Foo"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gadget"
Date = "3/2/2011"
Name = "Baz"

**Transaction:**
Type = "Gizmo"
Date = "3/1/2011"
Name = "Who"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fluent form:

```
var groups = transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Type)
                         .Select(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.Date).First());
```

In query form:

```
var groups = from t in transactions
             group t by t.Type into g 
             select g.OrderBy(t => t.Date).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var groupedTransactions = transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Type)
                                      .Select(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Is FirstOrDefault necessary?  If it's grouped, won't there be a date regardless, unless the date variable is nullable?

Comment: @Mike C.: The `FirstOrDefault` is unecessary and `First` will have the same semantics. The issue is not whether or note `Date` is nullable, but whether or not a group can be empty (in which case there would be no `First`). But a group can not be empty so the "`OrDefault`" never happens and `First` suffices.

Comment: @Mike C - Yeah, my bad it'll never occur since groupings will always have at least one element. Though what's a little null-check between friends. :)

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
var q =
from t in MyTypes
group t by t.Type into g
select g.OrderBy(t => t.Date).First();
```